# How to set a date range for scraping google search using Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I would like to know if it is possible to scrape google search specifying a date range. I read about `googlesearch` and I am trying to use its module (`search`). However it seems that something it is not working. 
Using `'cdr:1,cd_min:01/01/2020,cd_max:01/01/2020'` to search all results about a query (for example `Kevin Spacey`), it is not returning the expected urls. I guess something it is not working with the function (as defined in the library). Has someone ever tried to use it?
I am looking for results in Italian (only pages in Italian and with domain google.it). Another way to scrape these results would be also welcomed.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May this information help you: 
[image: Do Google search with browser]

Then, use the HTTP Spy to get the detail of the request. It's useful when Google changes their format of search, and the Module has not applied update to their code.
[image]

Good luck!